# How did the US Army put "The Abomination" in custody?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, marvel, the-incredible-hulk-2008

"How" both meaning , how did the US Army actually constrain "The Abomination" for the move to the place he is to be incarcerated and how did they hold him in incarceration?

He is obviously exhausted after the fight with hulk and does not seem to be unconscious, but even with a 100th of his original strength, he would still be too powerful to constrain.

So how did they do it?

Comment: A cryo-cell, as I recall.

Comment: related, but falls short of dupe: [Is Abomination free now?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56928/5184). The answers cover how *SHIELD* kept him contained, but not the military.

Comment: How did the US army put The Abomination in custody? *Very carefully.*

Comment: Your video went down.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure this has been answered before, but can't find it.

In **Agents of Shield Season 1 Episode 13 - Tracks** Coulson threatened Ward with Guard Duty over Emil Blonsky's (Abominations) cryo-prison cell at the *Fridge*, a Shield holding facility.

He is therefore kept frozen so as not to transform. 
The Fridge was raided by Hydra in a subsequent episode and many things removed. As there hasn't been any mention of Abomination causing havok it can be assumed he is still on ice.

Comment: This info was originally mentioned [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/84400/5184). Canon material puts Abomination in the custody of the US military prior to SHIELD, though.

Comment: “The Fridge was raided by Hydra in a subsequent episode and many things removed. As there hasn't been any mention of Abomination causing havok it can be assumed he is still on ice.” — I bet! “Hey Bob, shall we take this big grey guy with us?” “No way! The Hulk movie was *terrible*!”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite +1 for obvious reference to Hydra Bob